# create users on firebase using its authenticate methods

Tags: javascript, web, cors, firebase-authentication

i tried sending the credentials and this error appears.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=*******. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

```
(function () {

  var config = {
    apiKey: "*******",
    authDomain: "*******",
    databaseURL: "*******",
    projectId: "*******",
    storageBucket: "*******",
    messagingSenderId: "*******"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  const email = document.getElementById('email');
  const password = document.getElementById('password');
  const btnSignUp = document.getElementById('btnSignUp');

  btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const mail = email.value;
    const pass = password.value;

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mail, pass).catch(function(error) {

      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;

      if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
        alert('The password is too weak.');
      } else {
        alert(errorMessage);
      }
      console.log(error);

    });
  });
}());
```

How do I solve the CORS request blocked?

Comment: you have errors in your code `pass` is not allowed to be a variable name

Comment: thank you i just change it to passo so does this help in the error i was getting?

Comment: Does the error still show up? @Kae

Comment: yes @SheshankS.

Comment: where are you testing this? on localhost? wherever you are, is that url on the allowed domains in firebase/

Comment: i tried it on the localhost:5000 by running firebase serve I also deployed it on firebase hosting but still the same error and they are both allowed domains on firebase.

Comment: hmmmm that's interesting you usually don't have to worry about cors with firebase

Comment: Can you send the ` .firebaseapp.com` link here

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: weird you were able to add to the database!!!

Comment: However I am not able to do that !! @SheshankS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your firebase imports are wrong, use this:

```
<!-- Firebase App is always required and must be first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.1.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- Add additional services that you want to use -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.1.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

Comment: it is a trusted domain however I want to be able to send data when the website is on the localhost

Comment: i still have the same problem when you tested it did you try to change anything ?

Comment: yes can you send me a screen shot of the html code. I am new here I don't know everything here.

Comment: Add the html snippet above as the first thing in your <head></head> it should work make sure to clear cache

Comment: @Kae do CTRL + SHIFT + R on your page

Comment: the problem was with my html form!! thank you Sheshank S.

Comment: Can you clairfy the problem with your HTML which caused this? It can be useful to others.

Comment: @bojeil From what I know, he had a syntax error or something that broke his code. Normally if you recieve this error it's because of your imports